# How to cluster data and count it in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I would like to cluster all the different orders made in my dataset and count them so that I know which are the most frequently purchased products.

[image]

So far I can figured out how to group them but I still don't know how to cluster and count them.

```
 datasetProduct = dataset[dataset['Country'].isin(["White Metal Lantern"])].copy()
 datasetProduct.head()
```

Comment: Why don't you ever preface your questions with copy-able data? All you need to do is `print(df.head())` and paste the output here. Is that really harder than taking a screenshot, cropping it, uploading it, and pasting it here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to count the occurrence of `Description` column, you can do:

```
df["Description"]._value_counts()
```

This will list the occurrence of each unique item in the `Description` column in descending order.

Depending of what you want to do, you can also group your data by `Country` and get the unique counts of `Description` column for each country:

```
df.groupby("Country")["Description"].value_counts()
```

Comment: how can I filter it to the 100 most purchased items, right now it is showing all orders from the item which was ordered 1 time to the items which have been ordered 10000 times. I need to use only the 100 most ordered items.

Comment: @Dakata The result from above is a pandas Series, you can cut it just like it's a list, i.e. `df["Description"]._value_counts()[:100]`

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is the wrong tool if you want to **count** the most frequent products.

Just do a group by, and *count*, with no clustering.